# How can we recursively search through nexus repository?

Tags: python, bash, recursion, nexus

how can I recursively search through nexu directory?

I have a directories structure with many modules and submodules, and submodules have their own submodules. So it looks something like this:

```
<NEXUS_LINK>/project/module1
                      |_module12
                         |_V1.1
                         |_V1.2
                    /module2
                      |_V1.1
                    /module3
                      |_module31
                         |_module32
                            |_V1.1
                            |_V1.2
```

What I want to achieve? 
Sometimes i need to delete specific version e.g V1.2 and I need to search through this tree, find V1.2 direcotry and execute 
    curl -X DELETE -u admin:admin123 /project/../V1.2
Localy there is no problem but how to search throuh nexus directories?

Comment: try this one: `find /project/module1 -type d -name 'V1.2' -exec curl -X DELETE -u admin:admin123 {} \;`

Comment: The problem is <NEXUS_LINK> how can I use find through http?

Answer (score 0):

You could search via the API, e.g. `curl -u admin:admin123 -X GET 'http://<NEXUS_LINK>/service/rest/v1/search?repository=raw-hosted&group=/project'`

You could get a better search result if I knew what's your repository format and what's your search criteria. You can find more information about search API in the [documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- 50 assets limit
curl 'https://<NEXUS>/nexus/service/rest/v1/search?repository=<REPOSITORY_NAME>&group=project.module1.*&version=V1.*' 

-- then:
curl -X DELETE -u admin:admin123 'https://<NEXUS>/nexus/service/rest/v1/components/<IDs_FROM_RESP".items[].id">'
```

or

```
-- set own limit
curl 'https://<NEXUS>/nexus/service/extdirect' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-d '{"action":"coreui_Search","method":"read","data":[{"page":1,"start":0,"limit":1000,"filter":[{"property":"format","value":"maven2"},{"property":"version","value":"V1.*"},{"property":"attributes.maven2.groupId","value":"project.module1.*"},{"property":"repository_name","value":"<REPOSITORY_NAME>"}]}],"type":"rpc","tid":75}'

--delete by: 
".result.data[].group" 
".result.data[].name" 
".result.data[].version"
```